# I made a file descriptor and want the output on console (stdout) and this new fd - how?

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptors

I created a fd with `exec` and like to post the output on the new fd `3` and the stdout `1` - in my case the console.
I thought it's simple to concat this but wasn't able to find the correct syntax.

I checked https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html and https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/

Tought something like this: `nc -l 4444 1>&3` but sure it just links the stdout to my 3rd fd.
Or even simpler `echo test 1>&3`

So how can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

If `nc` only writes to one file descriptor, the output will only go to one file descriptor. There's no way to automatically duplicate it across two FDs – not just in shell syntax, but even at OS level.

So either nc has to be rewritten to write its output twice, or the output has to be piped to a separate "duplicator" program.

The standard `tee` tool is close to what you want, although it only takes file names, not file descriptors (aside from stdout, of course). But using it like this will let you get a similar effect, though on Linux it won't be 100% the same (its /dev/fd reopens the underlying file instead of just duplicating the FD):

```
nc -l 4444 | tee /dev/fd/3
```

Comment: Thanks, sure that was too simple but I did not get it. Thanks